# CSS format only a portion of the width of a div

Tags: html, css

I made a HTML volume bar:

```css
.volume_bar {
  background: #A5D5FF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="volume_bar"></div>
```

I am trying to format this volume bar, such that when there is a volume income, display the volume on the bar with another color. So it looks like this:
[image]

I got the reading volume input codes correct. I am just trying to figure out the frontend. One way I thought of achieving this is to format only a portion of the div. Such that 20% of the width is yellow, and the remaining is blue. Is that possible to only format a portion of the width of a div with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Change the width property of .volume class using javascript to make it work.

```js
document.querySelector(".volume").style.width="50%";
```

```css
.volume_bar {
  background: #A5D5FF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 12px;
}

.volume {
  background: #ffd105;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="volume_bar">
  <div class="volume"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const volume_bar = document.querySelector('.volume_bar');
const volume_control = document.querySelector('.volume_control');
const rect = volume_bar.getBoundingClientRect();    

volume_bar.addEventListener('mousemove', e=>{
    let per = (e.clientX - rect.x) / (rect.width) * 100; 
    volume_control.style.width = per + '%';
});
```

```css
.volume_bar,
.volume_control {
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 12px;
}

.volume_bar{
    background: #A5D5FF; 
}

.volume_control{
    background: red;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="volume_bar"><div class="volume_control"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes you can style a div so that the left is one color, the right another. Liner-gradient can make this effect. Your problem is the rounded edge of the left side - for that I think you need a second element, or pseudo selector.

Using linear-gradient() for easy effect but no rounded edge

```css
.volume {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, blue 30%, yellow 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="volume"></div>
```

Using psuedo selector:

```css
.volume {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: rgb(253 216 53);
}

.volume::after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: rgb(3 169 244);
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="volume"></div>
```